# Update Page Content without refreshing page?

Tags: php, html

If I included a file like this:

```
<?php
include "counter.php";
?>
```

..and my HTML is like this..

```
<p><?php echo $counter ?></p>
```

Is it possible to reread counter.php on a regular interval? The data in that file changes constantly and I would like to display those changes without reloading the page.

EDIT: $counter is a variable within counter.php

Comment: call ajax on some time interval

Comment: ..I have never used ajax :(

Comment: ...Is there I good to place to read about?

Comment: @FlameStinger you can read about ajax https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

for more ease you can use JQUERY FOR ajax requests